# Why using unicode in the format \u1F512 doesn't work in strings.xml?

Tags: android, unicode

I have a unicode string, which displays space followed by a lock symbol.It works if I declare it via the following way.

```
<string name="lock">\u0020</string>
```

[image]

---

However, if I declare it using the following way. It shows weird symbol

```
<string name="lock">\u0020\u1F512</string>
```

[image]

---

Based on https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F512 , I thought the unicode for lock symbol is `\u1F512`

---

May I know why it is so? How can I use `\u1F512`'s format in `strings.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u` syntax is used to encode Unicode codepoints in UTF-16 form.  As UTF-16 codeunits are 16bit values, only 4 hex digits following `\u` are used for encoding each codeunit.

The UTF-16 form of codepoint U+1F512 () is `0xD83D 0xDD12`, so to encode codepoint U+1F512 in `\u` form, you need to use `\uD83D\uDD12` instead of `\u1F512`:

```xml
<string name="lock">\u0020\uD83D\uDD12</string>
```

`\u1F512` gets interpreted as `\u1F51` followed by an unescaped `2`.  `\u1F51` is the encoded UTF-16 form for codepoint U+1F51 (`ὑ`).  That is why you see `ὑ2` instead of  in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your unicode value is not the lock symbol. You're actually pointing to `\u1F512` ὑ2 unicode symbol, and its encoded, and in hex...

try this  `\u0020\uD83D\uDD12`

[image]

Tada. An easy way to decode would be to use this website. https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

NOTE: It is also import, like with the website you posted a link to; To understand that there are differences with how an operating system handles unicode. For example, `\u1F512` **is NOT** the same as `\u0x0001F512` (In a UTF-8 context).

Basically Android and the IDE, are set to use UTF-8 by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

It's in all of your xml files. Because of this when you try to use UTF-16 or UTF-32 unicode encoding, you get something completely different from what you are actually trying to do.